# JQuery fadeIn and Load at same time

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I'm currently using Jquery load function to refresh parts of a page. The page called by `load` only outputs something to the div if certain db parameters are met. My problem is that at the moment when something is output is 'jumps' onto the page. e.g. it shifts the content above/below to fit itself in but looks messy.

I wanted to use Jquery fadeIn to combat this and have it fade in nicely but can't figure out how to do this with the `load` function.

The load function code is

```
$('#divToLoadInto').load('refresh.php?value=1');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this:

```
$('#divToLoadInto').load('refresh.php?value=1', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

That way the fadeIn will be performerd AFTER the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

try this code please that the loading and the fadeIn are in the same time.

```
 $('#divToLoadInto').load('refresh.php?value=1').fadeIn('slow');
```

also if you want that the fadeIn is after the load you can use the callback function like this:

```
$('#divToLoadInto').load('refresh.php?value=1', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

In this case you make the fadeIn after the load. Depends the effect that you want

Use $.post

```
 //create a div with id divhidden and hide it
 $("#divhidden").hide();
 $.post('refresh.php?value=1',function(response) { // (added quotes)
         $("#divhidden").html(response);
    });


$('#divToLoadInto').append($("#divhidden").show('slow'));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the desired effect in that it's still very jumpy and doesn't appear to fade. I'm now also playing around with having it fade and slide, to combat the jumpyness as well. I've been using this to fade and slide out but can't seem to apply it to `load` as well `$('#dmailrefresh').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: 'slow', queue: false }).slideUp('slow', clearDiv);`

Comment: you can load it into a hidden div and after append it to your div in fade @JamesKraw

Comment: I've tried various permutations of hiding the div either before or after the load and then fading in, the problem is that there isn't always content to be loaded, sometimes the refresh.php doesn't return anything but you still get the `slideDown` animation.

Comment: you can check if inside the refresh.php there is something. I update my answer with another solution @JamesKraw

Comment: Your updated answer looks like it could be right track. I'll test shortly. Only thing I'm confused on is what is response parameter and where does it get set

Comment: the response is the html of refresh.php you can print it make an alert like this and you see all the content: alert(response.html());

Comment: So is it set automatically as part of post call or will I need to populate it somewhere